# Complie Boost.Python code error: library not found for -lpython3.6m

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost, boost-python

I have an example code of Boost.Python

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
        {
                using namespace boost::python;
                def("greet", greet);
        }
```

And I compiled it with specifying Python3

```
g++ -o hello_ext.so -O2 hello.cpp -std=c++11 -fPIC -shared \
-Wall -Wextra `python3.6m-config --includes --libs` \ 
-lboost_python3
```

But I got the error

```
ld: library not found for -lpython3.6m
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Python**: Python3.6 on `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6`
**Boost.Python**: Installed using `brew install boost-python --with-python3`

The output of `python3.6m-config --includes --libs` is

```
-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m
-lpython3.6m -ldl -framework CoreFoundation
```

How can I compile my code by specifying python3 and boost.python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the directory provided by `python3.6m-config --ldflags`, make sure `libpython3.6m.dylib` is there. If so, add the options for the above command to your compiler invocation.

If it's not there, you need to build Python with `--enable-shared`.

Comment: The output of `python3.6m-config --ldflags` is `-L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin -lpython3.6m -ldl -framework CoreFoundation`. But after adding `--ldflags`, I got `ld: library not found for -lboost_python3`

Comment: Cool, so the problem with not finding the library for -lpython3.6m is resolved. You should really ask a separate question for the other issue.